# mongoid after_remove callback not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

this is my model:

```
class Country
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_many :cities, after_add: :show_log, after_remove: :show_log

  def show_log
    puts "this is log!"
  end
end
```

and here in console:

```
Country.first.cities.create FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:city)
=> [.....] this is log!
Country.first.cities.first.destroy
=> true
```

as you see in the second one, nothing is logged! what is wrong with mongoid after_remove?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are destroying the city from db. You should remove it only from relation:

```
Country.first.cities.destroy( Country.first.cities.first )
```